# Unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection, hikaricp

I am facing this problem for 2 hours.

The problem is I have other classes that are working well. I don't know why this error is happening for the current class.

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 351ms.
```

But the code works for other tables(other classes).

It was working so fine until today. Is there anyone that faced this problem before?

```
2020-03-13 13:52:25,392 [main] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -ScraperPool - idleTimeout is less than 10000ms, setting to default 600000ms.
2020-03-13 13:52:25,400 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -ScraperPool - configuration:
2020-03-13 13:52:25,406 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -allowPoolSuspension.............false
2020-03-13 13:52:25,407 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -autoCommit......................true
2020-03-13 13:52:25,407 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -catalog.........................none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,408 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -connectionInitSql...............none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,408 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -connectionTestQuery.............none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,409 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -connectionTimeout...............10000
2020-03-13 13:52:25,409 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -dataSource......................none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,409 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -dataSourceClassName.............none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,410 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -dataSourceJNDI..................none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,411 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>, prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048, cachePrepStmts=true, prepStmtCacheSize=250, leakDetectionThreshold=15000}
2020-03-13 13:52:25,412 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -driverClassName.................none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,412 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -healthCheckProperties...........{}
2020-03-13 13:52:25,412 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -healthCheckRegistry.............none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,413 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -idleTimeout.....................600000
2020-03-13 13:52:25,413 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -initializationFailTimeout.......1
2020-03-13 13:52:25,413 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -isolateInternalQueries..........false
2020-03-13 13:52:25,414 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://**********?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC
2020-03-13 13:52:25,414 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -leakDetectionThreshold..........10000
2020-03-13 13:52:25,414 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -maxLifetime.....................1800000
2020-03-13 13:52:25,414 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -maximumPoolSize.................100
2020-03-13 13:52:25,415 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -metricRegistry..................none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,415 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,415 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -minimumIdle.....................4
2020-03-13 13:52:25,415 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -password........................<masked>
2020-03-13 13:52:25,416 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -poolName........................"ScraperPool"
2020-03-13 13:52:25,416 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -readOnly........................false
2020-03-13 13:52:25,416 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -registerMbeans..................true
2020-03-13 13:52:25,417 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -scheduledExecutor...............none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,417 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -schema..........................none
2020-03-13 13:52:25,417 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -threadFactory...................internal
2020-03-13 13:52:25,417 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -transactionIsolation............default
2020-03-13 13:52:25,418 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -username........................"xxxxxxxxxxx"
2020-03-13 13:52:25,418 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -validationTimeout...............5000
2020-03-13 13:52:25,420 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -ScraperPool - Starting...
2020-03-13 13:52:25,452 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource -Loaded driver with class name com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver for jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://*********?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC
2020-03-13 13:52:27,099 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -ScraperPool - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@e84a8e1
2020-03-13 13:52:27,107 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -ScraperPool - Start completed.
2020-03-13 13:52:27,211 [ScraperPool housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -ScraperPool - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
2020-03-13 13:52:27,212 [ScraperPool housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -ScraperPool - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
2020-03-13 13:52:27,280 [ScraperPool connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -ScraperPool - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@58b0aed5
2020-03-13 13:52:27,346 [ScraperPool connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -ScraperPool - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@285edfdd
2020-03-13 13:52:27,414 [ScraperPool connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -ScraperPool - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@79a25ba1
2020-03-13 13:52:27,415 [ScraperPool connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -ScraperPool - After adding stats (total=4, active=0, idle=4, waiting=0)
```

I got this line before the error occured

```
DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=0)
```

Comment: Have you tried that? https://mkyong.com/jdbc/hikaripool-1-connection-is-not-available-request-timed-out-after-30002ms/

Comment: I added the debug STDOUT

Comment: There is no errors in your debug info. Probably you need copy and paste debug when error happens, not when successful.

Comment: 2020-03-13 14:11:51,134 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=0)

Comment: The page referenced by @Kosonome has useful information. You might read all the way through and check to make sure you don't have any leaky connections. Are you using Spring? Vanilla Java? What is your Hikari configuration? Beware of hidden defaults. I tend to explicitly configure everything explicitly when using Hikari. You might even make sure you're using the driver class you intended. My gut tells me this is a connection pooling issue but what you've provided doesn't point to anything in particular.

Comment: How large is the connection pool? From the DEBUG statement, I would guess that it has just one single member, and that is in use already … so getting another connection fails because there is none …

Comment: Could you show the hibernate configuration - connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the max limit of your pool. Below code tells you that pool reached max connection limit set in the config.

```
DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=0)
```